# Convert selected dataframe columns to vector representation (including duplicate values)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, vector

I have the below dataframe (product.csv) which I want to convert to vector representation:

```
product_id,value
111,3000
121,2500
131,3500
141,1000
111,3300
151,2000
161,2300
171,1300
181,1500
191,4500
121,6000
121,1100
```

My expected output should include all rows including duplicate product_ids and be in a vector form exactly as below:

**[111:3000; 121:2500; 131:3500; 141:1000; 111:3300; 151:2000; 161:2300; 171:1300; 181:1500; 191:4500; 121:6000; 121:1100]**

This is what I have tried so far:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('product.csv') #, index_col=0, sep=','

my_dict_indx = df.set_index('product_id')['value'].to_dict()
print(my_dict_indx)

my_dict_zip = dict(zip(df.product_id, df.value))
print(my_dict_zip)

my_dict_groupby = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).to_dict()
print(my_dict_groupby)
```

However, both `my_dict_indx = df.set_index('product_id')['value'].to_dict()` and `my_dict_zip = dict(zip(df.product_id, df.value))` give me the below output but exclude duplicate product_ids 111 and 121, do not return the correct order (e.g., output starts with 161:2300 instead of 111:3000):

> {161: 2300, 131: 3500, 171: 1300, 141: 1000, 111: 3300, 181: 1500,
> 151: 2000, 121: 1100, 191: 4500}

On the other hand `my_dict_groupby = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('r')).to_dict()` gives me the correct number of records and correct sequence below but includes unnecessary column indices, column names, and with no vector representation.

> {0: [{'product_id': 111, 'value': 3000}], 1: [{'product_id': 121,
> 'value': 2500}], 2: [{'product_id': 131, 'value': 3500}], 3:
> [{'product_id': 141, 'value': 1000}], 4: [{'product_id': 111, 'value':
> 3300}], 5: [{'product_id': 151, 'value': 2000}], 6: [{'product_id':
> 161, 'value': 2300}], 7: [{'product_id': 171, 'value': 1300}], 8:
> [{'product_id': 181, 'value': 1500}], 9: [{'product_id': 191, 'value':
> 4500}], 10: [{'product_id': 121, 'value': 6000}], 11: [{'product_id':
> 121, 'value': 1100}]}

How can I enhance my solution to achieve my expected output in [] vector form instead of {} dictionary form. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an the array of strings, because it's only way to support the output format you desire. Then you can simply use `.values` to get the column/array from the pandas series

```
df['output_col'] = (df['product_id'].astype(str) + ':' + df['value'].astype(str)).values
```

Output:

```
array(['111:3000', '121:2500', '131:3500', '141:1000', '111:3300',
       '151:2000', '161:2300', '171:1300', '181:1500', '191:4500',
       '121:6000', '121:1100'], dtype=object)
```

If you wish to have it as a list instead of an array, simply add `.tolist()` after the `.values` method. Finally, keep in mind that in Python a `,` is used to separate elements in an array/list instead of `;`

Comment: Adding to above answer, ```[k + ":" + v for k, v in df.astype(str).values]```

Comment: Nice alternative if those are the only columns!

Comment: Thanks so much. Your solution is very helpful.